# Django editable=False and still show in fieldsets?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an image field in my models.py...

```
 qr_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="public/uploads/",
        height_field="qr_image_height",
        width_field="qr_image_width",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False
    )
```

When it's `editable=False` I get a nasty error when trying show it. I don't want the field editable, however I do want the image to show in admin '**edit**' page i.e. **fieldsets**

I'm new to Django, can someone tell  me if this is possible and point me in the right direction here?

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish this is to make the field read-only in the ModelAdmin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Answer (score 20):

If you have a ModelAdmin like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Fieldset', {'fields': ['model_field', 'another_field', 'readonly_field']}),
    ]
```

where `readonly_field` has `editable=False` or if it is a DateTimeField with `auto_now_add=True` then visiting the admin page for your model will result in a field not found error.

To include a readonly field in your fieldsets, include `readonly_fields` like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Fieldset', {'fields': ['model_field', 'another_field', 'readonly_field']}),
    ]
    readonly_fields = ('readonly_field',)
```

Comment: Yes! `readonly_field` should be in `readonly_fields`, or raise `cannot be specified for User model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes` error

Comment: If only one field is in `readonly_fields` you need to add a comma at the end of the tuple: `('readonly_field',)` to avoid getting an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`